# передать параметр из hyperlink в View

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

У меня есть   @Html.ActionLink´ в HTML-коде.

```
Html.ActionLink("More",  "More", new { id = workShop.WorkShopId }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" , id ="moreButtonID" })
```

Из них мне надо вытащить value="id = workShop.WorkShopId" и отправить его с помощью POST запроса.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#moreButtonID').click(function () {

            var selectedWorkshop = $('#workShop.WorkShopId').val(); 

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("PaymentScreen", "Home")',
                datatype: "json",
                data: { wsCID: selectedWorkshop },
                success: function (data) {

                },
                error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                    alert(err);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я не очень понял почему вы конкретно берёте значение из ссылки, но могу предложить вот такое решение.

Вместо этого:

```
 var selectedWorkshop = $('#workShop.WorkShopId').val();
```

Можно сделать так:

```
  var selectedWorkshop = @workShop.WorkShopId
```